# Error compiling Qualnet on Mac: file is not of required architecture

Tags: c++, macos, linker

When trying to compile Qualnet on Mac, I got the following error:
ld: warning: in ../kernel/obj/mobility_private.o-darwin-x86-gcc-4.0, file is not of required architecture
and a bunch of errors for other files in this kind.
So I'm wondering if there is anyway to solve the problem.
Anxious waiting for help.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're trying to link objects of different architecture.

For example, having an object compiled for i386 (32 bits) and another compiled for x86_64 (64 bits).

Make sure all objects are compiled for the targeted architecture(s). Your options are:

1. Recompile `mobility_private.o` for 64 bits (-arch x86_64);
2. Recompile `mobility_private.o` for both 32 and 64 bits (-arch i386 -arch x86_64);
3. Recompile your application for 32 bits (-arch i386), so it correctly links against `mobility_private.o`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the architecture of a certain binary with *file*:

```
file libdynlib.so
libdynlib.so: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

You must compile your program to the same architecture of the libraries you are using. So, everything must be 32 bits or 64 bits.